# Load Image in groceryCRUD

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating codeigniter app.
I am using codeigniter + groceryCRUD and i want to display image in one column.

my code is

```html
function loadReport()
 {
  $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
     $crud->set_table('usermaster');
  $crud->columns('UserName','UserPswd'); 
  $crud->callback_column('xyz',array($this,'ShowImage_'));
      $output = $crud->render();
     $this->_example_output($output);
 }
 
 
 function ShowImage_($value,$row)
 {
  return "-- Image URL --";
 }
```

But it dosen't show my extra column in grid.

is any one here to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the full HTML, not the image URL:

```
function ShowImage_($value,$row)
{
    return '<img src="-- Image URL --">';
}
```